# how to set FileProvider for file in External Cache dir

Tags: android, android-intent

For file in Cache dir , I can add this in xml to set FileProvider

```
    <cache-path
    name="image"
    path="image/"/>
```

But if I storage file in External Cache Dir,I cannot get external-cache-path tag or something like that to set FileProvider.And

```
    <external-path
    name="image_external"
    path="cache/image/"/>
```

did not help ,too.

This is my Manifest file:

```
 <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.tizi.quanzi"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths"/>
 </provider>
```

This is the xml/file_paths file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <cache-path
        name="image"
        path="image/"/>
    <external-path
        name="image_external"
        path="cache/image/"/>
</paths>
```

And this is my Code:

```
String RootPath = App.getApplication().getExternalCacheDir().getAbsolutePath();
String filePath = RootPath + "/image/" + fileName;
// done something there to save file
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();

Uri contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(App.getApplication(),
        App.getApplication().getPackageName(), new File(filePath));
App.getApplication().grantUriPermission(App.getApplication().getPackageName(),
        contentUri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
shareIntent.setData(contentUri);
shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, contentUri);
shareIntent.setType("image/*");

activity.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "share image"));
```

And this is the error infomation:

```
    /AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.tizi.quanzi, PID: 27487
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.tizi.quanzi/cache/image/o9xygODHtdP6HXqsuUZghVCsBKTtY4FJgO1MpnmX.jpg
    at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider$SimplePathStrategy.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:678)
    at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:377)
    at com.tizi.quanzi.tool.ShareImage.shareImage(ShareImage.java:67)
    at com.tizi.quanzi.tool.ShareImage.shareImage(ShareImage.java:61)
    at com.tizi.quanzi.adapter.GalleryAdapter$2.onClick(GalleryAdapter.java:119)
    at android.support.v7.app.AlertController$AlertParams$3.onItemClick(AlertController.java:956)
    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:310)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1145)
    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3042)
    at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3879)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Update**:
The way to go with the Support Library 24.2.0 and above is how **@ashughes** says in his answer.

On that version they added two new tags to the implementation of [FileProvider.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/dcebe5a/v4/java/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.java) to be able to reference the external files and cache directories.

```
private static final String TAG_EXTERNAL_FILES = "external-files-path";
private static final String TAG_EXTERNAL_CACHE = "external-cache-path";
```

If you want to dig more into it, you can take a look at the changes made *[on this commit](https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/240521/)*.

**Original answer:**
I had the same problem. I took a look at the class `FileProvider.java`, and as you said, there is no tag for external cache dir, just the four below.

```
private static final String TAG_ROOT_PATH = "root-path";
private static final String TAG_FILES_PATH = "files-path";
private static final String TAG_CACHE_PATH = "cache-path";
private static final String TAG_EXTERNAL = "external-path";
```

What I do is to use the `external-path` tag. This tag will point to the root of the external directory not to the cache one. So you can either specify the rest of the path from there to the cache directory on `path`, or you can use a dot so it points to the root of the external directory.

```
   <external-path
    name="external_files"
    path="."/>
```

When you were using

> ```
> <external-path
>     name="image_external"
>     path="cache/image/"/>
> ```

The method `getFileForUri` was checking if the path of the file starts with `/storage/emulated/0/cache/image/` which it doesn't, because the path of your file is `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.tizi.quanzi/cache/image/`. And that's the reason you are getting the exception.

Comment: The lack of `external-cache-path` and `external-files-path` contradicts: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html. This is super annoying.

Comment: You must be using 24.2.0 or later of the support libs for `external-cache-path` and `external-files-path` to work.

Comment: This answer has made my day, thank you so much!
For other people who need to share the externalCacheDir with FileProvider - This is the solution.

Answer (score 6):

As of Support Library 24.2.0, you can use:

```
<external-cache-path name="name" path="path" />
```

See [FileProvider docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Following configuration works for me: 
I use

```
    <paths>
      <external-cache-path name="external_files" path="."/>
      <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
    </paths>
```

in my code.

and my provider looks like this

```
 <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.bqe.core.provider.CameraFilesProvider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/camera_files_provider_paths" />
```

my min sdk

```
           minSdkVersion 21
```